# Automation testing tools for Oracle Forms app?

Tags: automation, cucumber, oracleforms

I'm looking for toolset recommendations to automate testing of an Oracle Forms application, with the tests (ideally) to be driven from Cucumber.

I believe this is normal/unavoidable in apps based on Oracle Forms, but I'll spell it out anyway; the way the application works from an end-user perspective is:

- User connects via a browser, brings up the page for the application and logs in
- When user logs in, an applet is downloaded, and the Oracle Forms app starts in a separate window.  The user then interacts with the application via the Oracle Forms interface, leaving the browser window open (user can't shut down the browser while the Oracle Forms app is running, or the session will be lost)

Ideally, there'd be a toolset out there that can record the user's interactions with the Oracle Forms app, and we could insert steps into our Cucumber scenarios such as 
    `...When I type 'Bob Smith' into the 'Username' field
    And I hit the 'Submit' button...`, 
then have library code sitting behind the scenes to drive the Oracle Forms user interface at this level.

We'd also need to be able to check that various buttons/fields/whatever are displayed at the appropriate times, and the other normal functional-testing stuff...

Any suggestions as to tools that might let us build this behind-the-scenes library code?

Comment: Oracle's OpenScript (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/downloads/index-084446.html) looks like an automation tool that will work with Oracle Forms, but it looks pretty painful to try to bolt it into a Cucumber framework.  Is there a more Cucumber-friendly solution?

Comment: Nope, OpenScript didn't work out, but Sikuli seems to.  Not sure if it's really production ready though

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use Sikulix to automate the Oracle Forms in the applet in Cucumber "http://sikulix.com/"